# Is this raw type assignment type-safe? List<T> = new ArrayList();

Tags: java, generics, type-safety, raw-types

I have some code like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
List<String> theList = new ArrayList();
```

Is this type-safe? I think it is safe because I don't assign the raw type to anything else. I can even demonstrate that it performs type checking when I call `add`:

```
theList.add(601); // compilation error
```

I have read [*"What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) but I don't think it applies here because I only *create* the list with a raw type. After that, I assign it to a parameterized type, so what could go wrong?

Also, what about this?

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
List<String> anotherList = new ArrayList(theList);
```

Comment: The second one is dangerous because there is no restriction on what is in `theList`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first is type-safe because the list is empty, but still not advised. There's no *benefit* in using a raw type here. Better to design away from a warning than suppress it.

The second is definitely *not* type-safe, as `theList` may be a `List<Integer>` for example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        integers.add(0);

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList(integers);
        // Bang!
        String x = strings.get(0);
    }
}
```

Note how the constructor itself is called without an exception - there's no way for it to know what kind of list you're *really* trying to construct, so it doesn't perform any casts. However, when you then *fetch* a value, that implicitly casts to `String` and you get a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: *"There's no benefit in using a raw type here."* What if the generic parameter class is very long and I can't use the diamond? ; )

Comment: @Radiodef: Then use Guava and `Lists.newArrayList`, or an equivalent :)

Comment: Just curious, have you ever seen this turn in to a bug? I've thought about doing this before but it basically seems like a slippery slope. And aforementioned not actually being much of a point to it.

Comment: @Radiodef: I don't think so, but then I wouldn't do it anyway, so I couldn't see it in any of my own code :)