# Is the type parameter useful in the constructor of generic object instantiation?

Tags: java, generics, instantiation, diamond-operator

I know that since Java 7, repeating the type of a generic class in the constructor during the instantiation is a redundancy. But how about the diamond operator <>, is it optionnal to repeat it?
In other word, I would like to know what's the difference between this:

```
List<String> Fruits = new ArrayList<>();
```

and this

```
List<String> Fruits = new ArrayList();
```

or this

```
 Map<Integer, String> students = new HashMap<>();
```

and this

```
 Map<Integer, String> students = new HashMap();
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The raw type version (without the diamond) is unsafe, it lets you add to the List or Map without type checks (either by anonymous initialization or the conversion constructor). See [*Is this raw type assignment type-safe? List<T> = new ArrayList();*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203257/is-this-raw-type-assignment-type-safe-listt-new-arraylist)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a difference.  The diamond operator is just a shortcut for specifying the whole generic type, because it can be inferred.  These are equivalent:

```
List<String> Fruits = new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
List<String> Fruits = new ArrayList<String>();
```

However, with no angle brackets at all, that means you're using a raw type, which is different than using generics on the class.  This generates an unchecked assignment warning, and it should be avoided.

```
List<String> Fruits = new ArrayList();  // warning!
```

Comment: Ok, that's what I read on oracle website, but the problem I'm using new Netbeans 8 (the latest version of the IDE) and there's no warning when I write:  `List<String> Fruits = new ArrayList();` The assignment is checked and it doesn't compile when I assign a value other than a String in this example.