# What are the implications of a typed reference referring to an untyped object?

Tags: java, generics

What are the implications of this:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList();
```

When I say "implications", I mean, for using it in various scenarios, for example, passing to a function that expects a List, or a List, modifying the list, retrieving from the list, etc. I ask because to my mind *the reference is what we "pass around" to do things with*, and *the reference is typed* (as `List<String>`); but the compiler will complain about "unchecked or unsafe operations".

Thank you.

Edit: Thank you for pointing out the (possible) duplicate, but the answer given is unsatisfactory and merely reinforces my point:

> Stack s = new Stack() This will result in an "unchecked
>   conversion" warning, because it's not safe in general to convert a raw
>   type to a parameterized type. **However, it's perfectly safe to do so in
>   this case**: pushing Integer values will not cause any errors; pushing
>   non-Integer values will cause a type error.

I am asking, why is the compiler saying this is unsafe, when all we do is pass around and call methods on and with **references**, and **the reference is typed**. If I have a method `foo(List)` or `foo(List<String>)` and I want to call `foo` with my ArrayList, I will pass the reference `a`, not the object, and **the reference is typed**. So, what is the compiler complaining about exactly and why?

Comment: it will complain on new ArrayList() it should be new ArrayList<>() to allow type inference.

Comment: The compiler's required to give a warning any time you make an unchecked conversion like that regardless of the possible ramifications of the particular assignment. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22203300/2891664